# Add functionality to enable or disable user to use specific features on basis of invoice Assigned

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, middleware, laravel-8

I am working on a project in which I have three type of users **Admin** and **user1** and **user2**. I want **user1** and **user2** to able to use certain features in application only if the admin has assigned an invoice to them. I have tried using helper function given below.

```
 $invoice = Invoice::pluck('user_id')->toArray();
    if (Auth::user()->admin == 1 || in_array(Auth::user()->id, $invoice)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

but this does not work fine. I'll have to place it before every method of a controller in order to restrains users to use that feature. Is there any thing else I can do?
Any Better Approach for this?

Comment: Define a relationship between user table and invoice table.

Comment: hasOne() relationship will work for this?

Comment: Technically yes because your use case seems to authorize even if there is one invoice connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware).

Create your middleware with

```sh
php artisan make:middleware UserWithInvoiceMiddleware
```

Then open your file in `app/Http/Middleware/UserWithInvoiceMiddleware.php`, and add this to the `handle` method:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $invoice = Invoice::pluck('user_id')->toArray();

    if ($user->admin || in_array($user->id, $invoice)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Request not authorized.'], 401);
}
```

Also, you can create a relation in your user model with the Invoice model:

```php
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class);
}
```

Then, you can simplify your middleware using this relation:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (auth()->user()->admin || auth()->user()->has('invoice')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Request not authorized.'], 401);
}
```

You have to register your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, under the `$routeMiddleware` array:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 ...
 'user-with-invoice' => App\Http\Middleware\UserWithInvoiceMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then, you can protect your routes with this middleware, adding a `->middleware('user-with-invoice')` to the routes where the user has to be an admin or have an invoice:

```
Route::get('/example', ExampleController::class)->middleware('user-with-invoice');
```

Comment: Can I use this middleware to hide something in blade files like link to certain features?

Comment: You can use middleware to protect the link from being accessed, but you cannot hide the link using only middleware.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use make a middleware and pass requests throw it to check if the user is authorized to do that or not.

```
class SomeMidllewareName
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::pluck('user_id')->toArray();
        if (1 == Auth::user()->admin || in_array(Auth::user()->id, $invoice)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return \response()->json(['message' => 'you are not authorized'], 401);
    }
}
```

then, you can validate on the routes and you can use also **policies** and validate every feature alone